# Ionic : LocalFileSystem is not working in Cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

i am working on file system and using cordova file plugin for access file system of android. I am using:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fs) {
        fs.root.getDirectory(
            "ExampleProject",
            {
                create: true
            },
            function(dirEntry) {
                dirEntry.getFile(
                    "test.png", 
                    {
                        create: true, 
                        exclusive: false
                    }, 
                    function gotFileEntry(fe) {
                        var p = fe.toURL();
                        fe.remove();
                        ft = new FileTransfer();
                        ft.download(
                            encodeURI("http://ionicframework.com/img/ionic-logo-blog.png"),
                            p,
                            function(entry) {
                                $ionicLoading.hide();
                                $scope.imgFile = entry.toURL();
                            },
                            function(error) {
                                $ionicLoading.hide();
                                alert("Download Error Source -> " + error.source);
                            },
                            false,
                            null
                        );
                    }, 
                    function() {
                        $ionicLoading.hide();
                        alert("Get file failed");
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    },
    function() {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        alert("Request for filesystem failed");
    });
```

In browser its showing:

> Error: LocalFileSystem is not defined

and in mobile device (via Ionic View mobile app) its not working.

Please tell me is that right way to access file system ?

Comment: ost CordovaM plugins do not work in the browser, they are meant to work on mobile devices. Also could you tell us when this code is being executed? The code may be executing before the plugins are even loaded.

Comment: execute on ng-click="save()"

Comment: @rahul try request filesystem URL for device...

Comment: Can you please give me any example?